# Salto de linea en el texto obtenido por código de un tooltip en Angular

Tags: angular

En este proyecto: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Cuando quieres ver las empresas que han sido adjudicatarias de un concurso

[image: plicas]

Quiero que al poner el raton encima del boton "Adjudicada" el tooltip muestre las empresas una debajo de otra

[image: tooltip]

Pero no se que debo añadir en el contenido

En la plantilla tengo esto para el boton

```
<button *ngIf="element.estaAdjudicada==true" mat-raised-button color="accent"
          [matTooltip]="mostrarAdjudicatario(element)">Adjudicada</button>
        <button *ngIf="element.estaAdjudicada==undefined" mat-raised-button 
color="primary">Ver/Editar</button>
```

y en la funcion mostrarAdjudicatario() esto

```
mostrarAdjudicatario(oferta: Oferta): string {
var licitadorEnSolitarioId: number = oferta.licitacionesEnSolitario.find(o => o.adjudicado == true)?.licitadorId;
var uteId: number = oferta.licitacionesEnUte.find(o => o.adjudicado == true)?.uteId;
var licitadoresUteIds: string[];

if (licitadorEnSolitarioId != undefined) {
  return this.licitadores.find(l => l.id == licitadorEnSolitarioId).nombre;
}
else {
  licitadoresUteIds = this.utes.find(u => u.id == uteId).licitadoresId.split(",");

  var nombreUtes: string = ""

  for (let licitadorId of licitadoresUteIds) {
    nombreUtes += this.licitadores.find(l => l.id == +licitadorId).nombre + "&#13;"
  }
  return nombreUtes;
}

}
```

Pero no se que caracter añadir a nombreUtes para que se traduzca en un retorno de linea

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matTooltip` acepta un input `matTooltipClass` para añadirle clases al tooltip para personalizar su formato. Haciendo uso de este input puedes conseguir las múltiples líneas de la siguiente manera.

Asigna una clase al tootip (en este caso la he llamado `multi-line-tooltip`)

```
<button 
  *ngIf="element.estaAdjudicada==true" 
  mat-raised-button 
  color="accent"              
  [matTooltip]="mostrarAdjudicatario(element)"
  matTooltipClass="multi-line-tooltip"
>Adjudicada</button>
```

Añade esa clase en el archivo de estilos globales (**styles.css**) con la propiedad `white-space: pre-line`

```
// es necesario usar .mat-tooltip delate por temas de especificidad
.mat-tooltip.multi-line-tooltip { 
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Y por último inserta el salto de línea(`\n`) en la parte correspondiente del texto.

```
nombreUtes += this.licitadores.find(l => l.id == +licitadorId).nombre + "\n"
```

un saludo